# How can I ignore eol changes and all white space in svn?

Tags: svn, whitespace, eol

Combining svn diff --ignore-eol-style and --ignore-all-space is not working:

```
$ svn diff -x -w --ignore-eol-style -r 1143:1177 somefile
svn: invalid option: --ignore-eol-style
```

And,

```
$ svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style -x --ignore-all-space -r 1143:1177 somefile
```

Only executes the last option: ignore-all-space

Anybody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `svn` command seems to honour only *one* `-x` option. This means, you must/can combine *all* options into *one* argument:

```
    svn diff -x "-w --ignore-eol-style"
```

I did not test whether this is also true for external diff-tools.

Comment: If you get `diff: unrecognized option '--ignore-eol-style'` use the short form instead: `svn diff -x -w`

Comment: When you also want to suppress any newlines introduced or removed you should use an external diff program and add some options `svn diff --diff-cmd '/usr/bin/diff' -x '-u --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines' path1 path2` (-u gives the unified style as does svn diff)

Answer (score 3):

You can use external differencing tool with appropriate options (**diff-cmd** option in SVN config). Check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html). Then you have freedom to set any diff tool and provide arguments to it. You can also use it directly:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff --extensions "-b" -r 1143:1177 somefile
```

where **-b** to ignore white space at line end and consider all other sequences of one or more white space characters to be equivalent,